# how to plot split function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, piecewise

I am trying to plot ONE graph in MATLAB that has two functions that take different domains.

```
f1(t) = 50*t              % 0<=t<15
f2(t) = 160/3)*t - 180    % 15<=t<=60
```

I tried using below

```
t1 = 0:15;
y = f1(t1)
plot(t1,y)
hold on

t2 = 15:60 ;
y = f2(t2)
plot(t2,y)
hold off
```

then I get TWO graphs that do not form a continuous line.
[the graph from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8lcn.png)

I need the red graph starting at (15,750)
I can cheat and move the starting point for the second graph to be (15,750)
but is there a way I can graph these as one function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to define a single function where each term is multiplied by the condition for `t`, effectively zeroing it out when not applicable

```
f = @(t) (50*t).*(t<15) + ((160/3)*t - 180).*(t>=15);

t = 0:60;
plot( t, f(t) );
```

If your functions are complex then this could become slightly hard to read, but it's compact.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's my first question on StackOverflow, I didn't expect to get the input this soon. Your code looks very nice too ;-;

Comment: This did the job! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Two methods. Using loop and without loop.

```
f1 = @(t) 50*t              % 0<=t<15
f2 = @(t) 160/3*t - 180    % 15<=t<=60

t = 0:60 ; 
f = [f1(t(t<15)) f2(t(t>=15))] ;
plot(t,f)
```

With loop

```
f1 = @(t) 50*t              % 0<=t<15
f2 = @(t) 160/3*t - 180    % 15<=t<=60
f = zeros(size(t)) ;
for i = 1:length(t)
    if t(i) < 15
        f(i) = f1(t(i)) ;
    else
        f(i) = f2(t(i)) ;
    end
end
plot(t,f)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks a lot nicer in your first solution compared to mine :D

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I needed to make the domain uniform.

```
%setting domain t (0 <= t <15 and 15 <= t)
t = [0:30]; %suppose match time is 30 seconds

t1 = t(1:16);
t1(numel(t)) = 0; %f1 takes t1 as domain (0 <= t < 15):array 17-31 is filled with 0

t2 = t(16:31);
t2 = [zeros(1, max(0, 15)), t2];  %f2takes t2 as domain (15 <= t):array 1-16 is filled with 0
t2(1:16) = 15;   %array 0-16 is filled with 15, to cancel (t-15) in the function 

f= f1(t1) + f2(t2); %Moira's dmg from two domains are added to form one data set

plot(t,f, 'm--') %plotting f
```

[image: here is my end result using the method above]

I still need to get my domains correct I think.
The graph doesn't look as it is supposed to hahaha

Comment: It is conventional to edit your original question if the scope changes or it needs clarifying, otherwise existing answers can become obsolete

Comment: @Wolfie I didn't mean to make things complicated, I'm not quite familiar with how StackOverflow works. Thank you for letting me know!